# Redirect does not seem to do anything even when the condition is met (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect my user to a page once they have logged in by using Redirect, however I am not having much success. I am not getting any errors in the console, the page just simply does not change.

The `'/register'` page does exist and I have checked all of references of it throughout the application.

login page:

```
javascript
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';

import RegisterPage from '../components/User/RegisterPage.component';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import {createBrowserHistory, createHashHistory} from 'history';


import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    Redirect
  } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
        redirecting: false
    });

    const onSubmit =(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(state),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200){
                 
                console.log(res);
                
                localStorage.setItem("user", state.username);
                localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);

                
                <Redirect to="/register"/>
               

                var test = localStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
                console.log(test);
                
              
               
            } else {
                const error = new Error(res.error);
                throw error;
            }

        })
        .catch(err=> {
            console.log(err);
            alert("Error when logging in.")
        })

        
    };
   const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const {value, name} = event.target;
        setState((prevstate)=> ({
            ...prevstate,
            [name]:value
        }));
    };
    






    
return(
    <div>
        
    
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <h1>Login</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Enter username"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required
        />

                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

            </form>
</div>

            
        );
    };


export default LoginForm;
```

The issue appears tohave stemmed from this logic I added into the app.js file:

```
function App()
{
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("loggedIn");

  if(isLoggedIn === true){
  return(<Navigator/>)
  }
  else{
    return(<Login/>)
  }
}
export default App;
```

Navigator component file:

```
class Navigator extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(<Router>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
              <Container>
               
              <Nav className="justify-content-end">
                  <Nav>
                    <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                      Login
                    </Link>
                  </Nav>

    
                
                  </Nav>
    
    
                  <Nav className="justify-content-end">
                  <Nav>
                    <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                      Register a user
                    </Link>
                  </Nav>
    
    
                  
    
                  
                  </Nav>
    </Nav>    
                </Nav>
              </Container>
            </Navbar>
          </header>
    
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col md={12}>
                <div className="wrapper">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
                   </Switch>

                  
                  

                   

                   <Switch>
                       <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage}/>
                   </Switch>
                </div>
              </Col>
              </Row>
          </Container>
    
          
        </div>
      </Router>)
    }
}

export default Navigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(res => {
                if(res.status === 200){
                     
                    console.log(res);
                    
                    localStorage.setItem("user", state.username);
                    localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
    
                    
                    <Redirect to="/register"/>
                   
    
                    var test = localStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
                    console.log(test);
                    
                  
                   
                } else {
                    const error = new Error(res.error);
                    throw error;
                }
    
            });
```

Since you're trying to push the user to another router after a success response,

You could simply just do `history.push("/register")` don't `Redirect`

Comment: How would I go about implementing this? Would it be a case of changing the redirect to history.push?

Comment: exactly, instead of redirect, just do ```history.push()```, if you want to utilize the prevoius history i.e the prevoius page, just do ```history.goBack()```